# javascript .split() taking undefined values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of informations stored in localStorage who are split. The initial value of the localStorage is : `FC Girondins de Bordeaux*null*null*OSC Lille` . the split work fine but when i refresh the page. the value take : `FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille  undefined - undefined undefined`. How can i fix that ?

my app.js code :

```
.controller('myMatchsCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
   $scope.$storage= localStorage;
   console.log(localStorage);
   $scope.nbstore = localStorage.length;
   var tabAff = [];
   // show localStorage 
   for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
     localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ));
     tabAff[i] = localStorage[i+1].split("*");
     $scope.$storage[i+1] = tabAff[i][0] + " " + tabAff[i][1] + " - " + tabAff[i][2] + " " + tabAff[i][3];
   };
```

my html code :

```
<div id="myMatch" ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(nbstore+1) track by $index"  ng-if="nbstore">
    <h5> {{$storage[$index]}}</h5> 
    <label class="toggle" ng-model="myMatchsCtrl" ng-click="deleteMyMatch($storage[$index])">
        <input type="checkbox" checked ng-click="reloadPage()"/>
        <div class="track">
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

When you're doing your first split, you're overwriting the localStorage with your computed value.
Basically, here is what's happening:

```
tabAff[i] = "FC Girondins de Bordeaux*null*null*OSC Lille".split("*")
// tabAff[i] = [ "FC Girondins de Bordeaux", "null", "null", "OSC Lille" ]
```

Since $scope.$storage= localStorage, you're are putting

```
tabAff[i][0] + " " + tabAff[i][1] + " - " + tabAff[i][2] + " " + tabAff[i][3];
// = "FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille"
```

in the localStorage.

When you refresh the page, you are doing

```
"FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille".split("*")
```

which give you

```
tabAff[i] = [ "FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille" ]
```

So tabAff[i][0] = "FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille", 
and tabAff[i][1] = tabAff[i][2] = tabAff[i][3] = undefined

So 
`tabAff[i][0] + " " + tabAff[i][1] + " - " + tabAff[i][2] + " " + tabAff[i][3]`
gives you `FC Girondins de Bordeaux null - null OSC Lille  undefined - undefined undefined`

**Solution**

Don't overwrite the value in the localStorage (remove `$scope.$storage= localStorage;`) or store the computed value (`tabAff[i][0] + " " + tabAff[i][1] + " - " + tabAff[i][2] + " " + tabAff[i][3]`) in another part of the localStorage